# About my Transit Visa, DATV

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, datv

I am from India, I got a job offer from the Bahamas and have a Bahamas visa and work permit card. My ticket is Delhi to Bahamas Nassau with a layover in the UK. I am staying in UK only for 4 hours during the layover.

I would like to get my UK DATV, but my DATV has been refused 2 times, and in 2015 my Canada work permit visa was refused because I did not satisfy the visa officer with my financial status.

So right now I have got my Bahamas visa and work permit visa, I just need my UK DATV. Could you please advise me how to go about getting this?

Comment: In theory you are eligible https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa but with that history a different flight routing that isn’t via the UK seems a better idea.

Comment: Pass through a different country and avoid the UK even if the alternative ticket will cost more. That’s the safe choice.

Comment: @Traveller want to expand into a fuller answer?